# Logstash email output plugin throwing error

Tags: logstash

My logstash.version"=>"7.5.1"

```
Logstash config:
email {
      to => "to@email"
      from => "noreply@fromemail"
      subject => "Alert"
      body => '%{message}'
      port => 25
      debug => "true"
      address => "emailserverIP"
    }
```

```
Telnet and EHLO command:

telnet emailserverIP 25
Trying emailserverIP ...
Connected to emailserverIP .
Escape character is '^]'.
EHLO MyHostName
250-REXDB01.domain Hello [MyIP]
250-SIZE
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH NTLM
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250-XRDST
250 XSHADOWREQUEST
```

I am getting following error.
[ERROR][logstash.outputs.email ][email_alert] Something happen while delivering an email {:exception=>#}

Also tried following config

```
email {
      codec => "plain"
      to => "to@email"
      from => "noreply@fromemail"
      subject => "Alert"
      body => '%{message}'
      port => 25
      debug => "true"
      address => "emailserverIP"
      use_tls => false
      authentication => "plain"
      username => "noreply@fromemail"
      password => "1234567"
    }
```

```
email {
      codec => "plain"
      to => "to@email"
      from => "noreply@fromemail"
      subject => "Alert"
      body => '%{message}'
      port => 25
      debug => "true"
      address => "emailserverIP"
      use_tls => false
      authentication => "login"
      username => "noreply@fromemail"
      password => "1234567"
    }
```

then getting below error message
[ERROR][logstash.outputs.email   ][email_alert] Something happen while delivering an email {:exception=>#

Comment: Have you checked whether the email setting is correct? The error says that the application tries to sent an email however it fails, based on that, error may occurs in the delivery.

Comment: You were right @Edcel Cabrera Vista. IP was not allowed to send email. After adding IP to trusted list it worked fine. Thanks.